# Invalid class name from reflection .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to get all classes from the namespace:

```
var commands = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, nameSpace, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            .ToList();
```

I have only one class in this namespace:

[image]

But, in commands variable I have 2 classes:
[image]

I don't understand why it breaks. I also solved this trouble by adding
`!t.FullName!.Contains("<>")` in `where` statement of commands, but I don't think that it's perfect solution.
Can somebody explain me why reflection breaks?

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Did you try to print all the t.FullName in the namespace to see what exact type names returned? That will help you to write proper condition in where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing breaks, that's how classes generated by the compiler to run your code look like, specifically lambda functions, yieldable enumerable state machines and `async`/`await` state machines. It uses characters that C# explicitly doesn't support as part of identifiers (`<>`) on purpose, so there's never any clash, even though the CLR supports them.